# how to find out if it is a retry message in spring kafka Listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We are trying to solve an edge case scenario, in spring boot kafka listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics="topicName", groupId="consumerGoupId")
public void consumeNotification(@Payload Datarequest request,
                          @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) Long offset,
                          @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID)Integer partitionId) 
{
    processRequest(request);
}
```

Now for some reason when processRequest is going on, my spring boot app gets Shutdown,the offset doesn't get committed and when it is up,the listener picks up the same message for processing again.

My use case is : **Is there any way to know Listener has got this message as part of Retry?**

Because since process request was stopped in  between due to app Crash, if the same message has picked up by listener again, I have to write some logic in `processRequest` to start processing from where it stopped.

Answer (score 2):

Right; the only guarantee is at least once delivery; there is no way to know if a message has been redelivered (after a restart - we can tell if it's a redelivery in the same application instance - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#delivery-header).

Since you can't tell in all cases, you have to make your listener idempotent - e.g. by storing the topic/partition/offset along with the data, so you can check if it has already been processed.

Answer (score 1):

Thread.currentThread().getName() if Kafka retries name will contain "retry" for example:
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-retry-2-0-C-1
You can check if this String contains retry keyword then it is retry message.
And this is normal thread id name:
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1

Comment: That is only true if you are using non-blocking retries https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#retry-topic Blocking retries are delivered on the main thread.